# Avoid repetitive sub query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this Postgres query running fine but need to avoid repetitive sub query after NOT IN and IN clause.

```
=>(select video_id  from "PersonalInfo_history" where "PersonalInfo_history".user_id=5)
```

Postgres Query:

```sql
(
  select a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id as unseenvideo_id 
  from "Channel_subscribe" a  
    INNER JOIN "Videos_videos" b  
            ON a.channel_id=b.channel_id 
           and b.id NOT IN (select video_id  from "PersonalInfo_history" where "PersonalInfo_history".user_id=5) 
  where a.user_id=5 
  GROUP BY a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id 
  order by b.date desc
) 
UNION ALL  
(
  select a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id as unseenvideo_id 
  from "Channel_subscribe" a  
    INNER JOIN "Videos_videos" b  
            ON a.channel_id=b.channel_id 
           and b.id IN (select video_id  from "PersonalInfo_history" where "PersonalInfo_history".user_id=5) 
  where a.user_id=5 
  GROUP BY a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id 
  order by b.date desc
)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Assuming there are no NULL values in `video_id`, then you can just get rid of the IN and NOT IN and only use a single query without a UNION (btw the `order by` in each query is pretty useless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could extract it to a CTE?

```sql
with personal_history as (
    select video_id  from "PersonalInfo_history" where "PersonalInfo_history".user_id=5)
(
select a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id as unseenvideo_id 
from "Channel_subscribe" a  
INNER  JOIN "Videos_videos" b  ON a.channel_id=b.channel_id 
    and b.id NOT IN(select video_id from personal_history) 
where a.user_id=5 
GROUP BY a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id 
order by b.date desc) 
UNION ALL  
(select a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id as unseenvideo_id 
from "Channel_subscribe" a  
INNER  JOIN "Videos_videos" b  ON a.channel_id=b.channel_id 
    and b.id IN(select video_id from personal_history) 
where a.user_id=5 
GROUP BY a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id 
order by b.date desc)
```

even more compact version

```sql
with personal_history as (
    select video_id  from "PersonalInfo_history" where "PersonalInfo_history".user_id=5)
,
videos as (
    select b.*, ph.video_id is not null as is_in from "Videos_videos" b
    left join personal_history ph on ph.video_id = b.id
)
(select a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id as unseenvideo_id 
from "Channel_subscribe" a  
INNER  JOIN videos b ON a.channel_id=b.channel_id
where a.user_id=5 
GROUP BY a.user_id,b.channel_id,b.id,b.is_in
order by b.date desc)
```

not sure if it would work... kind of depends on your datamodel I guess, but it shouldn't be too far off?

Comment: ah yea of course. still removes some repetition... and a lot more can be removed with more CTEs

Comment: yes i tried that, it worked.However same query being used twice again

Comment: made an update that might solve the subquery being executed twice.